# How to pass literal parameter to advice method?

Tags: parameters, aop, literals

It is possible to pass a literal parameter to an advice method?

For example:

```
<aop:before pointcut="execution(public * anotherMethod(..))" method="myMethod(java.lang.String)"/>
```

In this example, I want to pass a literal String to "myMethod" before "anotherMethod" be executed. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate some more, optimally with some code snippets. I can understand your intent much better if I have a test case. As it is now, I do not even understand what you want to achieve.